# Reaching MaxRequestWorkers limits caused by bot traffic ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: apache, apache2, bots, maxrequestlength

I had an ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT and the website went down for a few minutes several times in a time-frame of approximately 1.5 hours, and this is something I found in the logs:

```
[Mon May 21 11:21:51.236380 2018] [mpm_worker:error] [pid 3206:tid 140035442734330] AH00287: server is within MinSpareThreads of MaxRequestWorkers, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting
```

I went to `/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` and found this:

```
MaxRequestWorkers [The number specified for my server]
```

I just changed server yesterday and this is one theory of the networking guys about what could be the cause of the problem:

> The server is hitting maxworkers due to the type of traffic that are
>   coming in, which are bot traffic. BingBot and Googlebot are crawling
>   your site again, likely because of the new server. You can manage the
>   crawl rate of these bots so that they do request so much at any given
>   time.

Is this a plausible explanation? I find this hard to believe.

Edit 1: It sounds like a denial-of-service (DDoS) attack performed by Google!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are even articles that talk about how bot traffic can affect a website:

- http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/telling-google-how-often-to-crawl-your-website
- https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/48620?hl=en
- http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/telling-bing-how-often-to-crawl-your-website
- http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/lets-get-started/how-to-use-robots-txt
- http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/apache-htaccess/user-agent-blocks-mainly-for-bots

I am not sure if bot traffic was really the cause of my problem, but the error message included this part: `consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting`. That is what I did and everything seems to be working correctly now.

IMPORTANT: If you do this, do not forget to read https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mpm_common.html and remember that if you increase MaxRequestWorkers, you will have to increase ServerLimit accordingly. The documentation explains that.